# Dropdown Navigation Tab doesn't work with doctype declaration

Tags: html, css, doctype

I created a dropdown navigation tab using 'li', 'ul' method in VS2010. I have a doctype declaration as

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The menu tab looks like this if the dropdown works without the doctype declaration.

[image: dropdown menu]

The dropdown works only when I remove the doctype declaration.I have tried 'frameset' and 'strict' declarations as well, but still no result. The code and the style sheet are below

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="menubtnback">
        <div id="navMenu">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="~/" style="width:65px">Home</a> 
                </li>
                <li> <a href="~/" style="width:150px">tab1</a> 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="~/" style="width:150px">subtab1</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="~/" style="width:150px">subtab2</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="~/" style="width:150px">subtab3</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="~/" style="width:150px">subtab4</a> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="~/" style="width:125px">tab2</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="~/" style="width:95px">tab3</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="~/" style="width:65px">tab4</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="~/" style="width:110px">tab5</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="~/" style="width:165px">tab6</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="~/" style="width:150px">tab7</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
```

STYLESHEET:

```
.menubtnback {
    background-image: url(Images/Icons/top-nav-back.jpg);
}
#navMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navMenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height:40px;
}
#navMenu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding :0;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-image:url(Images/Icons/top-nav-back.jpg);
    color:#000;
}
#navMenu ul li a {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:9.5pt;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    border-right:gray thin solid;
}
#navMenu ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:40px;
}
#navmenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:1004;
}
#navMenu li:hover {
    background-image:url(Images/Icons/nav-back.jpg);
    color:#FFF;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background-image:url(Images/Icons/nav-back.jpg);
    color:#FFF;
}
#navMenu a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Tables for layout smells like trouble. And you have an unclosed `<tr>` element.

Comment: oh, I have that closed on my code. I just posted the relevant part :)

Comment: Try porting your code into a Fiddle. What do you see?

Comment: I'm sorry, what's a fiddle ?

Comment: Also why is a 'doctype' declaration preventing a 'dropdown' from occuring ?

Comment: jsfiddle.com - post your code there and try to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of HTML you're declaring, what browser you're using, and a range of different issues.  A browser will treat different versions of HTML differently if you have declared them as such.

The doctype declaration for HTML5 is as simple as `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.

So, there's something going on between the doctype version you're declaring, the browser you're using, or the syntax of your doctype declaration.

http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Strict

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Transitional

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Frameset

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use all three declarations on all possible browsers, still no luck.

Comment: The following are the first three lines on my code                 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage2.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-gb" xml:lang="en-gb">

Comment: Have you tried using an HTML5 doctype declaration?  It's as simple as `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.  Do you see this problem across multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes I've tried that as well, and yes its not working in any of the browsers.

Comment: Well, without seeing all of your project code, I don't have a lot of advice to offer. If your site works without the `<!DOCTYPE>`, just omit the `<!DOCTYPE>`.  I don't believe anyone will think lesser of you for it.  As long as you're not using deprecated HTML features, you should be ok.